# Should I pre-cook sausages before scrambling into eggs?

Tags: food-safety, sausages

I have some fresh longaniza, maybe about 1 1/4" thick. Normally I'd throw them in the oven for 30-40 minutes or so then fry them real quick for texture.

I want to skin them, mash them, then mix them in with scrambled eggs or omelettes.

In terms of safety, should I still bake them before preparing them? Or mash them up raw and fry them for a while before adding the eggs? Or can I just throw the raw meat and eggs in the pan all at once?

They'll start cold, going from the fridge (~38F) to the oven/pan.

Comment: Not the question but like to drain the fat before adding to the eggs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It takes more heat/time to safely cook sausage than it does to fully cook eggs. This would be especially true for omelettes, where the egg is in contact with the hot pan, and the filling only warms indirectly. Add your expectation to start with cold sausage, and cooking the sausage and egg at the same time seems like a really bad idea. (Yes, you could just cook the whole assembly longer, but you'd end up with seriously vulcanized eggs.)

Be safe: cook the sausage, and then add the eggs.

Comment: Additional plus - the heated meat will help cook the eggs...

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't take 30-40 minutes cook eggs so you're going to have to cook them separately.  Cutting them up into small pieces and frying them will shorten the cook time, but not enough.  You could start cooking them that way alone in the pan and when they look cooked through add in the egg.

Note, that there seems to be a lot variation on what a "longaniza" sausage actually is. My answer assumes you're using a sausage that needs to be cooked. If you're using a cured sausage that's safe to eat uncooked then you can just cut them up and add them to the eggs.

Comment: Yeah, it's just that I'm mashing up the sausages, so I was thinking maybe the meat would cook really fast. But you're right. Btw these ones are uncured and raw.

Comment: @JasonC : it'll cook faster, but not fast enough.  Typically for me it takes 5-10 minutes (depending on how hot my pan is) for loose sausage to reach the point where I add other vegetables (bell pepper, onion, etc.), and then another 5 min or so before I add the egg (which only takes a minute or two to cook)